# Glassfish password alias

Tags: java, glassfish

I need to encapsulate the database passwords inside the glassfish JDBCConnectionPool.

I found in glassfish documentation how to encapsulate user admin password.

Would anyone have an example of the encapsulation of database passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *browse http://localhost:4848*
2. *Click --> domains --> Password Aliases --> New*
3. *Add your connection pool password in password field and Click OK.*

[image]

4.*Create a connection pool.When creating connection pool fill the password filed 
  as below.*

Example :

- ***${ALIAS=[your_password_alias_name]}***
- ***${ALIAS=test_pwd_alias}***

Answer (score 0):

Start you GF server and go to the admin console (usually localhost:4848) :

[image: Glassfish admin console]

- Then go to *Resources > JDBC > JDBC Connection pools*.
- Select your connection pool
- Go to the *Additional Properties* tab
- Here you will configure all your database connection info : username, database name, host (or database URL, depends on your DBMS), and password